# Undeliverable email to email service

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I am getting this error when writing email to my email service in my developer environment - using the email address I created the environment:

```
This message was created automatically by the mail system.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

>>> myemailservice@1tg6chj4oc8xpcatjre7pfdpa8bxwsuu9emdybfax2r7srgfba.9-p6epeaa.ap1.apex.salesforce.com (Undelivered): 554 The email service failed.
```

I checked the email service and the email address is added into both Email service and the email address' accepted email address list. I have also activated the email to Salesforce. I am now completely out of mind what is going wrong. It used to accept emails. I just updated my email service class and suddenly it stopped working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you done to your email service class? You may have inadvertently introduced a bug.

Comment: The original version is just some dummy code using hard-coded values. I added some real code which deals with the email body, analysed the string and updated the database. You are right it might introduce some bugs since I haven't tested it (the email doesn't work). But it shouldn't cause the email deliverable, am I right?

Comment: I think the error is not about your email being undeliverable, it could be your email service class has failed.

Comment: It shouldn't... Otherwise I should be able to see the error log at developer console, not by receiving an email back saying email not delivered.

Comment: Have you tried the debug log? I'm not sure whether you'll see anything related to email service in the developer console.

Comment: I just tried with an email service class with an uncaught exception and got the same error as yours.

Comment: @Kevin you should add this as an answer

Comment: @lance -- if you haven't already - insert try-catch into your inbound email handler - this will avoid the issue in the future. Your catch block can email the sysad with the details of the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with an email service class with an uncaught exception and got the same error as yours.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I looked into the code and got an null exception error. I fixed it and solved the issue